# Как найти подсказку о методе и его параметрах из командной строки?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я начинающий разработчик в ruby on rails. И мне бы очень помогло если бы я мог получить подсказку о параметрах метода (например File.open), из командной строки. Например help File.open.

Answer (score 2):

Можешь воспользоваться gem'ом [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). Он может использовать в т.ч. в стандартной rail-консоли. Для навигации по специфичной для rails информации (например routes) есть дополнительный gem [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails).

Вызов справки делается примерно так: `ri File.open`, где `File.open` - имя метода о котором хочется узнать.

На запрос `ri File.open` увидишь примерно такой ответ:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])                 -> file
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt])         -> file
  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj
  File.open(filename [, mode [, perm]] [, opt]) {|file| block } -> obj

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Только для стандартных методов потребуется `pry-doc`. Но `pry` и сам об этом скажет :)